# Most efficient way to send 100k emails and persist progress in a database in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, email, h2

Disclaimer: These emails are internal and the process is approved. There are no legal considerations to be made.

I have been building a rest API that allows creating email sending jobs. The API itself is simple, it just persists a job to to an H2 database and assigns recipients (also persisted) to it. A scheduled method then executed the jobs in the background, this works alright.

The performance issues seems to be persisting the information. Each recipient I hit is a database entity that has a sent flag that I set after the email was sent. It appears that doing this causes a slow down since there need to be a lot of queries. I somehow need to save my progress though, so not setting the flag would cause the job to run the same recipients again and again.

What could be an efficient way to handle this?

Currently:
Job gets 30 recipients from job that do not have flag set => Iterates over them => Sends email to each and marks as sent (+persisting) => Job repeats

30 recipients take about 5-10 seconds, meaning 100k recipients would take at least a day. Any idea how it could be sped up?

Comment: I find it unlikely that your database is the performance bottleneck. If a database could only handle 30 updates per 5-10 seconds, it would be totally useless. Your problem is elsewhere. If monitoring shows database being an issue, then you're likely keeping the transactions open for too long, and run into concurrency conflicts. Can't help with any of that without seeing some code.

Comment: I haven’t looked at Transactions more specifically yet, I was thinking that Spring Boot would handle transactions by itself if you use their built in database repository classes.

Comment: Sure, it likely will, but making updates takes locks in the database, that last until the end of the transaction. If you have many threads/processes, they end up having to wait for locks to be released. Commit the transactions will release locks and allow better concurrency.

Comment: Alright I’ll look into it, thanks :-)